# If Thunderbolt is a successor to DisplayPort, why can't it support DisplayPort multi-streaming?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

As a disclaimer: Yes, I know Thunderbolt (2) is multi-stream capable of up to 6 devices in a single chain. Yes, I *know* you can add a *single* DP monitor at the end of a Thunderbolt daisy-chain as an extended desktop. That said...

What prevents Thunderbolt from supporting DP 1.2a (mst)? I understand that the primary difference is Thunderbolt provides power along with its data connection. However, looking at articles like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29) it makes it sound as though it shouldn't have any issue allowing a DisplayPort-only daisy-chain.

For example, currently you could create such chains via Thunderbolt:

```
Mac --TB(2)--> TB Display --TB(2)--> External RAID --mDP 1.2a--> DP monitor

Mac --TB(2) #1--> TB Display --mDP 1.2a--> DP Monitor
 \----TB(2) #2--> TB Display --mDP 1.2a--> DP Monitor

Mac --mDP 1.2a--> DP Monitor
```

But you can't do this:

```
Mac --mDP 1.2a mst--> DisplayPort Monitor --mDP 1.2a mst--> DisplayPort Monitor
```

through a Thunderbolt port and configure them both as extended desktops (the second monitor will mirror the first one).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to and it may be a limitation of the system you are on or any intermediary devices.

Here's my setup:  Dell Precision M3800 with nvidia Quadro K1100m graphics.  Connected out of the Thunderbolt port (by a mDisplay port cable) to a Dell U3014 monitor which is connected to another U3014 (by a full size Display port cable).  I had to enable DP1.2 on the monitor in the settings for it to work.

I'm looking to see if I can use the Elgato Thunderbolt 2 Dock in between my laptop and the first display to utilize Network, USB, etc... in addition to dual displays.